# sampled_softmax_loss not decreasing while sequence_loss_by_example does

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am training an LSTM and using `sampled_softmax_loss` to compute the loss after each epoch (so many documents). I also compute the perplexity on a held-out set at the same time with `sequence_loss_by_example`.

The loss decreases for the first few epochs -- radically going down from 1-2. Then it just hangs around the same value (sometimes a little less; sometimes a little more). *On the other hand*, the perplexity does decrease consistently.

Why would loss stop decreasing while perplexity continues to go down? I expected both of them to decrease consistently.

Code looks something like this:

```
total_steps = 0
total_cost = 0.
for batch in train_epoch:
  total_steps += num_steps
  loss = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(...)
  cost = tf.reduce_sum(loss) / batch_size
  total_cost += cost
  ...
  optimizer.apply_gradients(tf.gradients(cost, vars),...)
print("average loss = {}".format(total_cost / total_steps))

total_steps = 0
total_xentropy = 0.
for batch in valid_epoch:
  total_steps += num_steps
  loss = tf.nn.seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example(...)
  total_xentropy += tf.reduce_sum(loss) / batch_size
print("perplexity = {}".format(np.exp(total_xentropy / total_steps))
```

Comment: can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

This observed behavior was resolved by reducing the learning rate. After that change, training loss and validation perplexity moved (mostly) in tandem.